# Fluent Validation - pass parameter to collection validator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

I'm using fluent validation i ASP.NET MVC application and I've had a problem.
This is my rule:

```
RuleFor(x => x.SimpleList)
       .SetCollectionValidator(new SimpleListValidator())
       .When(x => x.Type == SimpleEnum.SpecificType);
```

I want to pass x.Type param to SimpleListValidator, how can I do this? Some kind of extension method? It should looks like:

```
    RuleFor(x => x.SimpleList)
       .SetCollectionValidator(new SimpleListValidator(x => x.Type))
       .When(x => x.Type == SimpleEnum.SpecificType);
```

Comment: Hi, what's SimpleListValidator? 
Something is missing in the question?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter. It's some kind of validator which I want to apply on my list, but this "SimpleListValidator" takes one param in constructor and this is the case. Now I'm not able to pass lambda expression "x => x.Type" and I don't know how to build proper extension method like SetCollectionValidator.

Comment: If I understand right, SimpleListValidator CTOR gets 1 arg: Type, if so: Consider using typeof(X):

new SimpleListValidator(typeof(x)).
Will it work?

Comment: But x.Type it's not type of object, this is a field (enum) in class, it can be any other field etc. x.Name, x.Age..

Comment: Can you paste SimpleListValidator CTOR..

Comment: Why want you see SimpleListValidator? This is my class which derived from AbstractValidator<T>(from FluentValidation dll). The problem is in SetCollectionValidator extension method which takes only IValidator<TCollectionElement> which no possiblity to pass params to this IValidator which in my case is my "SimpleListValidator". If I'm wrong please correct me, but with tested solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you set collection validator for property - you can forget about fact, that main model and `(n - 1)` submodels exists except submodel being currently validated. And there is no way to pass main model as a parameter in `SetCollectionValidator`.

So you have to use `RuleForEach` method instead of setting collection validator:

```
RuleForEach(x => x.SubEntities)
    .Must((model, submodel) => IsValidFirst(submodel, model)) // your rules should go here to be applicable to each collection item
        .WithMessage("The item with values {0}, {1} has duplicates in collection of {2} items",
            (model, submodel) => submodel.Field1,
            (model, submodel) => submodel.Field2,
            (model, submodel) => model.SubEntities.Count); // for error message building you can access both model and submodel being validated
    .Must((model, submodel) => IsValidSecond(submodel, model)) // yet another rule
        .WithMessage("...")
    .When(model => 
        model.Type == SimpleEnum.SpecificType) // can access to main model only, but it is enough for your purposes
```

I guess that possibility to tell child validator about fact, that parent model could exists, should be implemented in future, but right now there is the only working approach, mentioned above.

**UPDATE**

You can create custom `ModelBinder`, that would set `Parent` property of each subentity to main entity value, and continue using `SetCollectionValidator()`.

Comment: Great, it's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 11):

It is possible and you can do it like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.SimpleList)
   .SetCollectionValidator(model => new SimpleListValidator(model))
   .When(x => x.Type == SimpleEnum.SpecificType);
```

In your SetCollectionValidator class you have to create a constructor accepting your model as a parameter (or anything else you'd like to pass to the validator). Remember though that you should leave a parameter-less constructor in the SimpleListValidator class.