# Prevent double validation message with FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

My validator checks if the property `Name` is unique, in the sense that no other item of the collection `ContentSections` has the same value.

```
public class ContentSectionDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<ContentSectionDto>
{
    public ContentSectionDtoValidator(EditContentSectionsDto editContentSectionsDto)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .Must(x => editContentSectionsDto.ContentSections.Count(contentSection => contentSection.Name == x) == 1)
            .WithMessage("The Name '{0}' has already been used. Names must ne unique.", x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

In order to achieve that, I passed as parameter to the constructor the parent model, which contains the entire collection, so I can compare the `Name` of the current item to the one of all the other items of the collection.

This works, but obviously in case the `Name` if found to be in use by any other item, a validation error for each match is printed.

[image]

Is there a way to only print ONE message even if the condition is matched many times?

Comment: You can use RuleForEach method in the parent model validator. Look at example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32354428/571203).